# Silverlight text trimming and wrapping issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have the following layout in XAML:

```
    <StackPanel Height="40">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"  Margin="0,10,0,10"
                               LineHeight="18" FontSize="12">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dapibus commodo dui vulputate laoreet. Donec metus purus, consectetur ut sagittis ut, vestibulum id diam. Suspendisse in urna sem. Ut purus arcu, placerat quis tempus cursus, elementum sed sem. Duis condimentum semper tortor, a pulvinar dolor semper sit amet.
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

So inside my stackpanel there is a textbox. In this example I set the height in the parent stackpanel, but in my real application it is set some level higher.

I have to display the text in multiline and use ellipsis as trimming behavior. The problem  is if I use the XAML code above, the last line of the text gets cut. I've attached a screenshot to illustrate the behavior:

[image: text gets cut]

Is there a way to solve this issue? The expected behavior would be to show only the first line and the ellipsis at the end of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the issue caused because of I used StackPanels. The content's height, inside the StackPanel was as big as it should be to display all content in it. However, the parent StackPanel have a height limit, and the content inside  got clipped.

I've replaced my StackPanel to a Grid and trimming & wrapping works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

> The TextTrimming property has no effect unless the TextWrapping
>   property is set to NoWrap.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way to create multiline, trimmed text in SL4? And how can I achieve what I mentioned if I don't want trimming?

Comment: You would probably have to add some behaviour which looks at the size of the TextBlock.  Then create a new TextBlock in code with the same width as your TextBlock but no size constraints.  Then keep adding text to the new TextBlock so you know how much it can take without exceeding the height of the original TextBlock.  Then run some custom trimming function which adds the ellipsis.  Possible, but not exactly trivial :)

Comment: Are you sure about the correctness of that MSDN article? In this article (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/90849/Text-Trimming-in-Silverlight-4) a textblock is used with trimming and wrapping. However the problem is that it only works if I set the height & width on my textblock, not the panel around it.

Comment: Interesting - I haven't tested that case, but if it works, you could probably add a much simpler behaviour which binds the height of the textblock to that of its container.