# Silverlight TextBlock TextTrimming inside ContentControl disappears

Tags: silverlight, textblock, contentcontrol, texttrimming

I'm displaying a series of messages (like emails) on a Grid:

```
<layout:TransitioningContentControl Name="tccCmdMessage" Margin="0,4">
    <layout:TransitioningContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                <TextBlock Name="tbCmdMessage" Text="{Binding Message}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </layout:TransitioningContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</layout:TransitioningContentControl>
```

However, the tbCmdMessage never displays. If I remove the TextTrimming (or change it to None) it works. Alternatively if I don't use a ContentControl parent it also works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/30fd3279-7bc8-424f-9ee6-41b9f9589a1a.

I suppose explicitly specifying the `Width` (or `MaxWidth`) of the `StackPanel` can make the texts trimmed. You can also try to use another type of container, like `Grid`.

Other links with similar issue described:

- [Silverlight text trimming and wrapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242732/silverlight-text-trimming-and-wrapping-issue)
- [TextTrimming not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370455/texttrimming-not-working)
- http://forums.silverlight.net/t/58227.aspx/1

Comment: I understand the sentiment of the response and I did actually look at all those links prior to my post (I was lazy about changing the StackPanel to something else) but in my case the symptom is slightly different. It's not that I'm not getting the "...", I'm not getting any text displayed at all.

Comment: FTR, I Changed the StackPanel to a Grid with 2 columns. Result was the same.

Comment: The issues described in the links are a little different, but I supposed the solution could be similar. You wrote it doesn't work, so I'll look for some other solutions.

Comment: Thanks for taking interest in a resolution. The only thing I narrowed it down to was the contentcontrol (I did try just a ContentControl and got the same problem). It's not the end of the world. For now, I'm just living with the potential truncation of really long text (I could implement a mouse over tooltip or something I guess...I was hoping to use something I previously downloaded which does this for you).